# Execution Stuck at Get-PnPPage if function executed on Button Click

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-api

Powershell Version: 7.4.1
PnP version: PnP.PowerShell 2.4.0
I am trying to create pages from Sharepoint template using following function.

```
function New-ArticlePage {
    param (
        $PageName,
        $PageTitle,
        $PageSubHeader
    )
    $TemplateURL = "Templates/article-template.aspx"
    
    Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SharepointSite -Interactive
    $Template = Get-PnPPage -Identity $TemplateURL  
    Remove-PnPPage -Identity $PageName -Force
    $Template.Save($PageName) 
    Set-PnPPage -Identity $PageName -Title $PageTitle | out-null
    Set-PnPPageTextPart -Page $PageName -InstanceId 1fca516d-4584-448d-8fff-2c0d5ab10318 -Text PageSubHeader

}
```

If I execute the function from a Button click event, the execution halts at following line

```
$Template = Get-PnPPage -Identity $TemplateURL
```

Button code:

```
$Button_CreatePage = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $Button_CreatePage.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(100,335) 
    $Button_CreatePage.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(195,23)
    $Button_CreatePage.Text = "Create Page"
    $Groupbox_ArticleTemplateModel.Controls.Add($Button_CreatePage)
    $Button_CreatePage.Add_Click(
        {
            New-ArticlePage -PageName $Textbox_PageName.Text -PageTitle $Textbox_PageTitle.Text -PageSubHeader $Textbox_PageSubHeader.Text
        }
    )
```

If I execute the function directly with params it creates page as expected. But if I place the same code inside Add_click function it halts at `Get-PnPPage -Identity $TemplateURL`

```
New-ArticlePage -PageName $PageName -PageTitle $PageTitle -PageSubHeader $PageSubHeader
```

Comment: Does it look like `Connect-PnPOnline` completes successfully inside the function? I think you can do `Get-PnPConnection` after it to see. My guess is that doing inside a forms button suppresses some part of the `-Interactive` prompt

Comment: Yes. `Connect-PnPOnline` Completes successfully. Other PnP commands like `Add-PnPFile`, `Resolve-PnPFolder` are working properly.

Comment: One observation, if I call the function before `$main_form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form` function executes, but if I call just after I create a new form object `$main_form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form` it halts at `Get-PnPPage`

following works
```
New-ArticlePage -PageName $PageName -PageTitle $PageTitle -PageSubHeader $PageSubHeader 
$main_form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
```
but below doesn't
```
$main_form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
New-ArticlePage -PageName $PageName -PageTitle $PageTitle -PageSubHeader $PageSubHeader 
```

Comment: Weird. Does it support `-Verbose` or `-Debug` output? The form object itself shouldn't* have anything to do with it. Does it continue to happen in a clean powershell session with only those three commands: define function > create form > `New-ArticlePage`

Comment: Yes this is happening in a clean session as well. This issue is happening only for `*-PnPPpage` commands.